# removeObjectAtIndex causes "message sent to deallocated instance"

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting

I am converting some code to ARC. The code searches for an element in an NSMutableArray, then finds, removes, and returns that element. The problem is that the element gets deallocated immediately upon "removeObjectAtIndex":

```
- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(int)tag
{
    UIView *view = nil;
    for (int i = 0; i < [self count]; i++)
    {
        UIView *aView = [self objectAtIndex:i];
        if (aView.tag == tag) 
        {
            view = aView;
            NSLog(@"%@",view); // 1 (view is good)
            [self removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            break;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",view); // 2 (view has been deallocated)
    return view;
}
```

When I run it, I get

```
*** -[UIView respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x87882f0
```

at the second log statement.

Pre-ARC, I was careful to retain the object before calling removeObjectAtIndex:, and then to autorelease it. How do I tell ARC to do the same thing?

Comment: What does `[self removeObjectAtIndex:i];` do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare the `UIView *view` reference with the `__autoreleasing` qualifier, like so:

```
- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(int)tag
{
    __autoreleasing UIView *view;
    __unsafe_unretained UIView *aView;

    for (int i = 0; i < [self count]; i++)
    {
        aView = [self objectAtIndex:i];
        if (aView.tag == tag) 
        {
            view = aView;
            //Since you declared "view" as __autoreleasing,
            //the pre-ARC equivalent would be:
            //view = [[aView retain] autorelease];

            [self removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            break;
        }
    }

    return view;
}
```

`__autoreleasing` will give you ***exactly*** what you want because on assignment the new pointee is retained, autoreleased, and then stored into the lvalue.

See the [ARC reference](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.restrictions.autoreleasing)

Comment: I thought `__strong` is the default? Wont it do this anyway?

Comment: Thank you Jacob. Two things: 

1) I had to use __unsafe_unretained instead of __weak, because I wish to maintain iOS 4 compatibility.
2) Turns out ARC was NOT turned on for that file. Dumb mistake. I had to go through and remove "fno-obj-arc" in the target->build phases->compile sources section.

Comment: Do the original code crash even when you turned on ARC? Or do you still need to mark the local variables?